# How to query a record across the database with id

Tags: orientdb

I have a custom unique index called "id" in all my vertices and edges. I want something like

```
Select * from * where id='1234'
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: you can get the list of the table names `select name from( select expand(classes) from metadata:schema` and then cycle on them with your query: https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/sql/SQL-Metadata.html

Comment: nope I tried it all.. it ain't helping.

Comment: What do you mean? some code please. Moreover, if you defined a class hierarchy with an index on the base class it could work: `select from BaseClass where id = 1234 `

Comment: wow that's exactly what I wanted
Select * from V where id='1234' worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select * from V where id='1234'
```

worked like a charm!